# How to print all columns when columns are dynamic and one common column is present?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Lets say i have 2 table A,B .In both the tables (id) is the common column ,and rest columns dynamic.so write a query to print id of "A" and rest all columns .
A(id,name,city),B(id,phone,phone_num). Here I only know "id" column ,rest columns(name,city,phone) are coming dynamically,So i can not use A.name,A.city,B.phone etc .In

```
select * from A FULL OUTER JOIN B ON A.id = B.id;
```

is printing id column twice.

Comment: Didn't get what's the problem. Show some sample data and expected result.

Comment: Can you use dynamic SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display the `id` column only once, use the `using` clause for the join :

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA a
   JOIN tableB b using (id)
```

The `using` clause as the effect that the join column(s) are only included once with `select *`.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong, you want to display all the column of both the tables and the common column i.e id should come only once.If that's the case use the below query and replace the column name with the column names you want to display.

```
SELECT a.id,a.column1,a.column2,b.column1,b.column2
FROM tableA a
INNER JOIN tableB b ON a.id=b.id
```

Comment: yes but in my case i don't know the rest column names .So i can not use a.column1,a.column2,,b.column1,b.column2 .

Comment: @Sidhartha How can you not know the names of the column. Is it a temp table??

Answer (score 0):

Demo

```
create table my_table_1 (id int,c1 int,c2 int,c3 int);
create table my_table_2 (id int,c4 int,c5 int);
```

---

```
select      array_to_string(array_agg (table_name || '.' || column_name::text),',')
from        information_schema.columns
where       table_name in ('my_table_1','my_table_2')
        and not (table_name,column_name) = ('my_table_2','id')
```

> my_table_1.id,my_table_1.c1,my_table_1.c2,my_table_1.c3,my_table_2.c4,my_table_2.c5

Comment: But this not printing the values.It is only showing the record count.

Comment: There is no "static" way to retrieve all columns except for one. This can only be done in a dynamic code and this is how you can generate the list of columns.